# PDFTex Error (conv-xkv.sty not found)

Tags: errors

I get the following error when I try to run

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{insdljs}
```

inside my TeX document.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `conv-xkv.sty' not found.
```

What do I need to do? Where do I have to put conv-xkv.sty after downloading it? I'm using a Windows (10) PC with MikTeX 2.9.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to download and install the package [`conv-xkv`](https://ctan.org/pkg/conv-xkv) manually, because MiKTeX [supports](https://miktex.org/packages/conv-xkv) it.
Open the MiKTeX package manager and install the package `conv-xkv`.